# Print from the last appearance of the line

Tags: c++

can someone help me to print everything from the last line appeared to the end (**THIS IS ONE INFO**).
In my document i have 3 appearances of line("THIS IS ONE INFO") but a want to print everything from the last appearance.
I don't know how to do an algorithm to calculate if there are 3 occurrences of that line, print all after the 3rd line, or if there are 6 occurrences print all after the 6th etc.

**This is some of my code**

```
        ifstream ifile("D:\\mytext.txt");
        input.open("D:\\mytext.txt");
        if (input.is_open())
        {

        BEGIN:

            while (getline(input, line))
            {
                if (line.find("**THIS IS ONE INFO**") != string::npos) {
                    cout << "Print line" << line << endl;
                    ++found;
                        }
                        else
                    found == hlp;
                pos = line.find("DATA/DATE");
                pos2 = line.find("PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE");
                id = line.find("AID:");
               ...........
                if (line == "PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE") {
                            outFile << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
                            outFile << "\n" << endl;
                            found++;
                            hlp++;
                            cout << "hlp= " << hlp<< endl;
                            cout << "Found= " << found<< endl;
                            goto BEGIN;

                        }.....
```

This is my output document:

```
10:39:42 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 500 FUNCTION 5000
10:39:48 INFORMATION REQUEST AC A  B 
10:40:04 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 620 FUNCTION 5000
**THIS IS ONE INFO**
================ INFO ================
2018.07.18 10:23:41  - 4784
IDCR: 1111520
SOLUTION: A:5 B:5 C:5
=================================================
DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     ID00302 
----------------------------------------
AID: A11111111111

**************************************

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
10:23:09 INFORMATION REQUEST AB
10:23:09 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 010 FUNCTION 5000
10:40:06 INFORMATION REQUEST    ACCBB
Decline reason message:  Common decline
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:52 INFORMATION REQUEST  A AA CB
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047
**THIS IS ONE INFO**
================ INFO ================
2018.07.18 10:23:41  - 4784
IDCR: 1111520
SOLUTION: A:5 B:5 C:5
=================================================
DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     ID00302 
----------------------------------------
AID: A2222222222222

**************************************

PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
10:23:09 INFORMATION REQUEST AB
10:23:09 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 010 FUNCTION 5000
10:39:42 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:39:42 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 500 FUNCTION 5000
10:40:04 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 620 FUNCTION 5000
10:40:06 INFORMATION REQUEST    ACCBB
**THIS IS ONE INFO**
================ INFO ================
2018.07.18 10:40:41  - 1235
IDCR: 1111220
SOLUTION: A:5 B:5 C:5
=================================================
10:22:23 INFORMATION REQUEST AB    C 
10:22:24 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT  FUNCTION 5
10:22:32 INFORMATION REQUEST AA      
10:22:32 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 0 FUNCTION 100
10:22:53 INFORMATION REPLY NEXT 104 FUNCTION 2047
DATA/DATE      TIME     TERMINAL
2019.07.16     20:07:27     ID00302 
----------------------------------------
AID: A333333333



PLEASE CONTACT YOUR OFFICE
----------------------------------------
APPROVAL CODE:
Decline reason message:  Common decline
=================================================
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on the fly by filling the data into an `std::string` line by line and clearing the data each time the current line contains the desired pattern ("THIS IS ONE INFO" in this case).

This would result in the end to having the contents from the last occurrence of the pattern to the end of the file (which is what you want).

---

- A possible implementation:

```
int main()
{
    const std::string path_file("path/to/some_data.txt");

    std::ifstream ifs(path_file);
    if(ifs)
    {
        std::string data;
        std::string pattern("THIS IS ONE INFO");

        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(ifs, line))
        {
            data += (line + '\n');
            if(line.find(pattern) != std::string::npos)
                data.clear();
        }

        // Print the desired contents
        std::cout << data;

        ifs.close(); // Optional: If not used, the destructor will perform it.
    }
    else
        std::cout << "[Error] Could not open file: " << path_file << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- Tested with the following file contents:

```
foo
THIS IS ONE INFO
bar
baz
**THIS IS ONE INFO**
foobar
foobaz
```

And the output was (as expected):

> foobar
>   foobaz

---

If you don't want to do it on the fly, you can read the whole file into a `std::string` and then getting the desired data by using [`std::string::rfind()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/).

This will search for the last occurrence of the given pattern and will return the position of the first character of the match (or `std::string::npos` if there is no match).
At this point, you just have to extract the substring from this position to the end.

*I don't write an example for this solution since I think the idea is quite trivial. If it not the case for you, let me know and I will provide it anyway.*

Comment: Thanks for answer @Fareanor, but can i get the number of occurrence of the pattern? I try it with counter but it count all the lines not the occurance. `while(std::getline(ifs, line))
        {
            data += (line + '\n');
            if(line.find("THIS IS ONE INFO") != std::string::npos)
                data.clear();
              ++count;
        }
cout<<count;`

Comment: @DDS Yes of course, each time you have to clear the data string, you just have to increment a counter. The number of clears is the number of occurrences :)

Comment: But in my case it gave me that the number of counter is =8, not = 2. I got it, i have to put **++count** out from `while()`. Thanks

Comment: Of course, `data.clear()` and `++count;` must be both inside the `if` condition. You forgot to wrap them between braces. Remember that the `if` will only apply on the following instruction without braces. So it is: `if(line.find("THIS IS ONE INFO") != std::string::npos) {data.clear(); ++count;}`